# How to compile a simple ruby script with macruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, macruby

I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello World" ruby script to a Mac OS binary using macrubyc.
This is the command I'm using:

`macrubyc -C hello_world.rb`

This is the output of the `file` command:

```
file hello_world.rbo
hello_world.rbo: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

However, when I try to run the created binary, I get `./hello_world.rbo: cannot execute binary file`

PS: The hello_world.rb script contains just a single line:

`puts "Hello World!"`

Comment: That's only half the process; you still need to link it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not linking your program.
Invoke macrubyc like this:

```
macrubyc -o hello_word hello_world.rb
```

When you run `macruby -C` it creates an object file which has to be linked in order to be executed.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks
I thought that the -C switch did the linking.